# how to assign a value to global variable in runtime in python

Tags: python-2.7

While running a code in python I want to update a dictionary value that is in config(global variable) I'm trying to do but i got the following error.

config.py

```
survey={'url':''}
```

runnigcode.py

```
url=config.__getattribute__(config.environment)
url['url']='myurl.com'

TypeError: "'module' object does not support item assignment"
```

Comment: It would be better if you add your code by editing your question.

Comment: Can anybody tell me how can edit the global variable during runtime

Answer (score 0):

in your runningcode.py, just import the variable as a method:

```
from config import survey

print survey
```

if you want to modify the value in the config.py, just use write method, like in this post: [Edit configuration file through python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299092/edit-configuration-file-through-python)