# Change value in ini file using ConfigParser Python

Tags: python, ini, configparser

So, I have this settings.ini :

```
[SETTINGS]

value = 1
```

And this python script

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('settings.ini')

print parser.get('SETTINGS', 'value')
```

As you can see, I want to read and then replace the value "1" by another one. All I was able to do so far is to read it. I searched on the net how to replace it but I didn't find.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As from the examples of the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

```
parser.set('SETTINGS', 'value', '15')


# Writing our configuration file to 'example.ini'
with open('example.ini', 'wb') as configfile:
    parser.write(configfile)
```

Comment: For Python 3.5+ you have to use 'w', not 'wb'!

Comment: SafeConfigParser deprecated
```  DeprecationWarning: The SafeConfigParser class has been renamed to ConfigParser in Python 3.2. This alias will be removed in future versions. Use ConfigParser directly instead.
  'os':operating_system, 'arch':arch}) ```

Comment: If you make your code a complete example, it would show declaration of `parser` and the filename would match given question, i.e. `'settings.ini'` to actually _change_ the file contents.

Answer (score 9):

Python's official [docs on `configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#quick-start) illustrate how to read, modify and write a config-file.

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('settings.ini')
config.set('SETTINGS', 'value','15')

with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with:`with open`

Other way:

```
import configparser

def set_value_in_property_file(file_path, section, key, value):
    config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read(file_path)
    config.set(section,key,value)                         
    cfgfile = open(file_path,'w')
    config.write(cfgfile, space_around_delimiters=False)  # use flag in case case you need to avoid white space.
    cfgfile.close()
```

It can be used for modifying java properties file: `file.properties`

Comment: deleted my original config.ini file

Comment: @skpro19 I was trying again on linux and win. ini and properties file behave the same. No issue with deleted file. Win (python 3.4.1) linux (python 3.6.8). I was trying with various configuration of file/directory access

Comment: Don't need to justify why not using `with open ..`. Your solution works. Only the comment has a small typo ("case case") and Java-related [properties file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) note is a bit confusing here, because question is about [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) ️

Answer (score 2):

Below example will help change the value in the ini file:

```
PROJECT_HOME="/test/"
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read("{}/conf/cdc_config.ini".format(PROJECT_HOME))
parser.set("default","project_home",str(PROJECT_HOME))


with open('{}/conf/cdc_config.ini'.format(PROJECT_HOME), 'w') as configfile:
    parser.write(configfile)
```

```
[default]
project_home = /Mypath/
```

Comment: Question, in your snippet, these curly brackets in open method, {} they mean relative path?

Comment: @deokyong song that is a formatting method.  see [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for more information on string formatting.

Comment: I think that `str(PROJECT_HOME)` is not necessary, because `PROJECT_HOME` is defined as a string. So, I think, this should work the same: `parser.set("default","project_home",PROJECT_HOME)`